# Perl wrongly complaining about Name "main::FILE" used only once

Tags: perl, file, warnings

I simplified my program to the following trivial snippet and I'm still getting the message

> Name "main::FILE" used only once: possible typo...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use autodie qw(open close);

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
    local $/;
    open FILE, "<", $f;
    local $_ = <FILE>; # <--- HERE
    close FILE;
    print $_;
}
```

which obviously isn't true as it gets used three times. For whatever reason, only the marked occurrence counts.

I am aware about nicer ways to open a file (using a $filehandle), but it doesn't pay for short script, does it? So how can I get rid of the wrong warning?

Comment: 1. Can't reproduce. 2. Why is adding 6 chars such a hardship? You can practically make it up by changing `foreach` to `for`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either (using perl 5.20.2). Does the problem still occur if `-w` is removed from the shebang and replaced with `use warnings;`?

Comment: What version is your Perl interpreter? `perl -v`

Comment: @ikegami 2. It's no hardship, it's just that that I'm used to the old way. Moreover, `FILE` is pretty obviously a FILE and it's a nicely identifier.

Comment: Assuming I agree with you that `FILE` is obviously a file handle, `$FILE` would be just as obvious.

Comment: I can reproduce this on 5.10.1.

Comment: @ikegami You're right... for whatever reason I saw there a difference, but it's really just those 6 more chars. It's perfectly simple and logical... my bad and thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie#BUGS) for `autodie`:

> BUGS
>
> "Used only once" warnings can be generated when autodie or Fatal is used with package filehandles (eg, FILE ). Scalar filehandles are strongly recommended instead.

I get the warning on Perl 5.10.1, but not 5.16.3, so there may be something else going on as well.